# [C]Im trying to compare a string value in a struct with another string

Tags: c, struct

```
void searchSong(struct Playlist **playlist, char *title) {
    if (*playlist == NULL) {
        printf("Playlist empty\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    struct Playlist *searchMe = *playlist;
    while ( strcmp(searchMe->title, title) != 0){
            searchMe = searchMe->next;
    }
    printf("%s %s",searchMe->title ,searchMe->artist);

}
```

I want to keep comparing the string values in the struct. I kept getting a SIGSEGV what am I doing wrong? Im new to C.

Comment: After moving `searchMe` pointer to its `next`, you should check whether `searchMe` is `NULL` or not and if it is not then only go for `strcmp()`.

Comment: You're going to want to check if `searchMe->next == NULL` at some point to stop the loop when you reach the end.

Comment: Why do you pass `**playlist` when `*playlist` is all you use?  It's strange you have an `exit(1)` if the playlist is NULL opposed to return value that caller can exit on it or not.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the function signature to take a `struct Playlist *` and return one as well so caller can tell if search was successful or not.  Then added a minimal implementation of what you didn't share with us so I could test the function.  The loop iterates through the list till `p2` is no longer set.  This means in the loop body `p2` is non-NULL that can be safely dereferenced:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Playlist {
    char *artist;
    char *title;
    struct Playlist *next;
};

struct Playlist *searchSong(struct Playlist *p, char *title) {
    if(!p) {
        printf("Playlist empty\n");
        return p;
    }

    for(struct Playlist *p2 = p; p2; p2 = p2->next) {
        if(!strcmp(p2->title, title)) {
            printf("%s %s\n", p2->title, p2->artist);
            return p2;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    struct Playlist *p = &(struct Playlist) {
        "a", "b", &(struct Playlist) { "c", "d", NULL }
    };
    assert(!searchSong(p, "a"));
    assert(searchSong(p, "b"));
    assert(!searchSong(p, "c"));
    assert(searchSong(p, "d"));
}
```

Btw, I would simplify `searchSong()` by moving the empty check and print functionality to separate functions.